# Magento2. Error with attributes on front-end

Tags: magento-2.1, attributes, attribute-value

After filling in all field in an attribute (id160) i get an error on the frontend when loading this page.

```
(Exception): Notice: Array to string conversion in /vendor/magento/module-catalog/Block/Product/View/Attributes.php on line 84
```

It has to do with this piece of code:

```
public function getAdditionalData(array $excludeAttr = [])
    {
        $data = [];
        $product = $this->getProduct();
        $attributes = $product->getAttributes();
        foreach ($attributes as $attribute) {
            if ($attribute->getIsVisibleOnFront() && !in_array($attribute->getAttributeCode(), $excludeAttr)) {
                $value = $attribute->getFrontend()->getValue($product);

                if (!$product->hasData($attribute->getAttributeCode())) {
                    $value = __('N/A');
                } elseif ((string)$value == '') {
                    $value = __('No');
                } elseif ($attribute->getFrontendInput() == 'price' && is_string($value)) {
                    $value = $this->priceCurrency->convertAndFormat($value);
                }

                if (($value instanceof Phrase || is_string($value)) && strlen($value)) {
                    $data[$attribute->getAttributeCode()] = [
                        'label' => __($attribute->getStoreLabel()),
                        'value' => $value,
                        'code' => $attribute->getAttributeCode(),
                    ];
                }
            }
        }
        return $data;
    }
```

and line 84 is  `} elseif ((string)$value == '') {`

When i comment this line and the next line the problem is fixed for now.

But what does this line do? And is there a other way to solve it?

I have magento 2.1.7ce

Answer (score 1):

If you want to convert `$value` to string, you just need a little PHP twist
on line 84:

```
} elseif (implode("", $value) == '') {
```

Comment: Hi, I am not a programmer. Could you tel me in normal language why this is needed?

Comment: It can convert an array to string. But wait, what is the data type of `id160`?

Comment: This attribute has a lot (200+) sizes. Numbers, letters, braces () and a combination of these. Like 122-128 (7-8y)

Comment: And this error only shows with products who use this attribute. When an other product uses an other size attribute nothing is wrong)